# Forwarding all mail to a single dev box on IIS via virtual SMTP

Tags: iis, smtp, virtual

I am trying to set up a development environment for our web server. I would like all emails that are relayed by the server go to a specific mailbox, regardless of who they were sent to. For example, some application on the server sends an email to shopper@yahoo.com. I want that email to go to devbox@mysite.com. Is that possible to do with IIS/Virtual SMTP? Is there some other way of doing this? I don't have exchange server running, if that makes a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: May be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 utilities that I found quite useful:

1. PaperCut http://papercut.codeplex.com/
2. Antix (doesn't always work) http://www.antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTPServerForDevelopers